# How to save login session using Swifter?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, twitter, oauth

I successfully authenticate my twitter account using this library (https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter).

but how do I save the session? so if everytime I exit and open the application again I don't need to relogin.

if I save the accessToken on NSUserDefaults what should I do next? I haven't found any method in this library to restore the session using accessToken.

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand what I'm asking about.

spent hours looking for the solution but I haven't found any answers yet from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this : https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter/issues/71

I'm also facing this issues without success, even with the above link, but maybe you will be more successfull.

(sorry can't anwser in your post directly, not enought stars)